# System call from php

Tags: php, system, exe

I'd like to use in php the following command. It works fine with 1 part of my console application, when I print into file. But When I save a picture or smth with the given function, it didn't do anything.

```
  system("cmd /c C:\Apache24\htdocs\PSTools\Psexec.exe -i C:/Apache24/htdocs/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe paramter1 .... parametern");
```

On the Other Hand When I put the same `C:\Apache24\htdocs\PSTools\Psexec.exe -i C:/Apache24/htdocs/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe paramter1 .... parametern` into Console. It is running without any problems. I don't know what can cause the problem.

****** Edit *****

I have tried changing everycombinations of \ and / but still didn't solve the problem. Also in the 1st section I wrote: **It works fine with 1 part of my console application**

So the problem is not with the calling, but can be permissions(Everything have admin rights-first get it to work then I rethink), etc.

****** Additional Info ******

I use Psexec(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx), because of the -i connector.

Comment: I could be wrong, but have you tried changing the `/` in the path to a back slash?

I know in the command line windows changes `/` to a back slash automatically, but I'm not sure if the automatic replace will happen through PHP

Comment: As I wrote 1 part of my code is running with changing only the parameters. But I tried your tip didn't solve the problem. :)

Comment: Also, again I could be wrong, but with PHP strings you need to use double back slashes... So "C:\path\to\file" becomes "C:\\path\\to\\file". Again these are simple things so you may have already tried them. Sorry if I am just repeating things you already know hahaa

Comment: Are you running PHP through a webserver? Are you sure the webserver user has access to `Psexec.exe` and `ConsoleApplication1`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, 1 part of my code is running. When I change 0 to 1 in my parameter list

Comment: Terminology warning. A [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is used by a program to request services from the operating system's kernel. The fact that PHP (and many other languages) includes a function named `system()` is unfortunate.

Comment: Use Task Manager->Details to see which user your web server is running as. This user needs permission to write to the location that your script is trying to write to.

Comment: Yes I know that, but Since I need interaction with graphical interface. (Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject (or could be Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel etc.)

I cannot use exec I think could'nt get it to work because I need to run from cmd(not apache service) for Interops, otherwise I'll have to deal a much bigger problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Steve E. It is on Administrator, that have full controll on everything.

Comment: Some thingies I tried:
1.Not working with a new user, same full rights.
2. I tried with exec and bat(Working on using bat), but not from php.

**exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Apache24\htdocs\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\run.bat');**

3. Triple checked httpd.exe (Apache http Server running by Adminisitrator that have full rights)

4. Gave all of the exes admin rights again.

5. I forgot to tell ofc, printing into files are handled by 3rd party tool. So that's the reason why I could print into file.
---->
Thus There is still a permission problem with the save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a move around. The PHP writes into a file, then my new console application listen for the file C#:

```
        while (true)
        {
            while (IsFileLocked(myFile))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            /*    Do stuffs   */
        }
```

Like this I reached my goal.